# for loop in to create matrix if estimates

Tags: r

```
data=c(2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,2,1,2,4,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,1) ## population data
X=matrix(data,4) ## four samples each of size 10
X
```

I want to estimate parameters for each row (each sample) of data through this distribution.

```
DGIWD=function(x,t1,a1,b1) t1^(b1/(x+1))^a1- t1^(b1/(x))^a1
library(MASS)

jk<-fitdistr(x =X[1,],densfun = DGIWD,start = list(t1=0.6,a1 =3,b1=2.3)) ### estimates parameters for first row X[1,]
jk

jk$estimate[1] ## first estimate 
jk$estimate[2] ## 2nd estimate
jk$estimate[3] ## 3rd estimate
```

I am interested in running a for loop for estimation of parameters and I want to store the parameters in a matrix
There are total 4 sample and parameters are three so I want to store parameters in 4X3 matrix as below

```
estimates<-matrix(NA,nrow=4,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
estimates
```

Could you help, how to handle such a situation.

I my self tried now

```
h=function(X){
DGIWD=function(x,t1,a1,b1) t1^(b1/(x+1))^a1- t1^(b1/(x))^a1
library(MASS)
jk<-fitdistr(x =X,densfun = DGIWD,start = list(t1=0.6,a1 =3,b1=2.3)) ### estimates parameters for first row X[1,]
jk
}
X <-list(1:3,4:6,7:9)
data=c(2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,2,1,2,4,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,1) ## population data
X=matrix(data,4) ## four samples in five rows

apply(X,1,h)
a=(do.call(rbind,apply(X,1,h)))[,1]
b=as.matrix.data.frame(unlist(a))
```

But still not able to get 4X3 matrix

Comment: As you mentioned `##Five samples in five rows` but when I run your code, and print `dim(X)`  then it displays out as `4 rows` and `10 columns`.

Comment: @ Saurabh, you are right, actually a typing error. These are four samples each of size 10.

Comment: Kindly update your question by correcting the typos.

Comment: @ Saurabh , updated

Comment: I have added step by step code for the solution. Kindly go through the solution.

Comment: [You should take care of this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Does the following solution okay for you? I haven't received any response.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the following R code :

```
data=c(2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,4,3,2,1,4,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,2,1,2,4,1,1,3,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,1) ## population data
X=matrix(data,4) ## four samples each of size 10 
DGIWD=function(x,t1,a1,b1) t1^(b1/(x+1))^a1- t1^(b1/(x))^a1
library(MASS)
jk=c() #Create empty vector
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
 a=fitdistr(x =X[i,],densfun = DGIWD,start = list(t1=0.6,a1=3,b1=2.3)) 
 jk=c(jk,a$estimate) #Append the result to vector jk
}
final_matrix=matrix(jk,nrow = nrow(X),byrow = TRUE) # Convert vector to matrix
```

The output of the above code is shown below:

```
> X
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    2    2    1    2    2    4    1    2     2
 [2,]    3    1    4    4    1    2    1    2    2     3
 [3,]    2    2    3    3    3    1    1    1    2     2
 [4,]    2    2    2    1    2    2    3    2    2     1
> jk
   t1        a1        b1        t1        a1        b1        t1     a1        b1 
  0.5353273 5.6575948 2.3487268 0.5601999 2.9350104 2.6272016 0.5550104 4.0996826 2.4168878 
   t1        a1        b1 
0.5582317 7.0411706 2.3134498 
> final_matrix
        [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.5353273 5.657595 2.348727
[2,] 0.5601999 2.935010 2.627202
[3,] 0.5550104 4.099683 2.416888
[4,] 0.5582317 7.041171 2.313450
```

In above output, `final_matrix` is your desired output with 4X3 dimension. Hope it works for you!

Comment: @ Saurabh, could you please help with this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054371/creating-model-function-in-r

Comment: @BilalPara- If you agree with answer provided by me then please mark the answer as accepted.